# Valid Palindrome solution in Python not working

Tags: python, palindrome

I'm working on a solution for finding a valid palindrome, where an empty string would be considered a valid palindrome. This question ignores any cases which are not alphanumeric.
Following are some examples:

```
Input: "A man, a plan, a canal: Panama"
Output: true

Input: "race a car"
Output: false
```

I wrote a solution where if I encounter a non-alphanumeric character, that character would be skipped:

```
def isPalindrome(self, s):
1        """
2        :type s: str
3        :rtype: bool
4        """
5        """
6        for i in s:
7            if (i.isupper())==True:
8                i.lower()
9        """
10        if len(s)==0:
11            return True
12        print(s)

13        i = 0
14        j = len(s) - 1

15        while(i<=j):  
16            if s[i].isalnum()==False:
17                i+=1
18            elif s[j].isalnum() == False:
19                j-=1
20            elif s[i].islower() != s[j].islower():
21                return False
22            i+=1
23            j-=1
24            
25        return True
```

However I keep on getting the following result:

```
Your input
"A man, a plan, a canal: Panama"
stdout
A man, a plan, a canal: Panama


Output
false

Expected
true
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.
Your posted code simply defines a function (intended as a method?) and quits.  You show no effort to trace the problem.

Comment: See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.
If nothing else, some strategic `print` statements will trace your control and data flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem jumped out at me as I was about to close this tab:

```
        elif s[i].islower() != s[j].islower():
```

This is *not* the comparison you need.  `islower` returns whether or not the letter is lower case.  This will fail on your first attempt, comparing `'A'.islower()` (which is `False`) against `'a'.islower()` (which is `True`).  The comparison you need is

```
        elif s[i].lower() != s[j].lower():
```

i.e. drop both letters to lower-case and compare them.

There are more problems in your index handling, but this -- and a few `print` commands -- should get you moving.

Comment: you're right. I made this change in my program. However I'm still getting an error, namely 'IndexError: string out of range'. on line 16:   
16            if s[i].isalnum()==False:

Comment: i fixed the indexing, thanks for your help. instead of using the if and elif statements, I've used while statements:  while (i<j and s[i].isalnum()==False):
                i+=1
            while (i<j and s[j].isalnum() == False):
                j-=1